# How to make a variable to remember the previous length of the list?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting API data from the backend using axios and in `.then()`.
What I'm trying to do is when another client is added and I get it to the list, I want to make a statement that notices the new client on the list, and after it to complete the statement.
My idea is to compare the length of the list, and if in the list is added a client, the length would be added + 1.
But the thing is that every time the page is rendered, the list is re-updated as well since I'm doing it with useEffect.
So my idea is to make a variable that remembers the previous length on a list in a state, and if a new client comes to the list the condition might be `clientList.length > prev.clinetListlength`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const clientParams =
      "userName=" +
      currentUser
      "clientId=" +
      currentClient
    setClientList([]);
    axios
      .get(API + clientParams)
      .then((response) => {
        let newListClient = response.data.map(function (client) {
          return {
            ...client,
            id: client.cleint_id,
            name: client.client_name,
            created: client.created,
          };
        });
        setClientList(newListClient);

        //the logic...:
        if(newListClient.length > prev.newListClient) {
           console.log("test")
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

What makes it hard, on my behalf is the useEffect that re-renders the list every time, so it might be hard to remember a previous length bc it is updated as a new one every time, which in this case the `console.log("test")` is shown every time.

Comment: UseEffect with [] calls only once if you want to listen for new user pass clientList to dependence list

Comment: [1.] if you want, you can maintain a redux store for this.
[2.] use class component with component lifecycle methods (you can compare current and previous state)
[3.] maintain another state to store the previous data and call useEffect when currentList is updated (add the newListClient into the array of useEffect)
[4.] use useRef()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.localStorage` to store previous values. here is an example of some code

```
const prevLen = window.localStorage.getItem('prevLen')
window.localStorage.setItem('prevLen' , newListClient.length)
// you can make you're logic like so
```

Comment: Did your logic, it works, but the problem is when I delete a client, and right after I add a client, it doesn't work. How can I make it work

Comment: whenever you delete the client also update list length in localStorage

Comment: but in the delete function id used a list with another name variable, so should I do it on the delete function ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `LocalStorage` will be enough for your issue. The idea is to put your length to browser level and update it, write additional useEffect

```
   useEffect(() => {
   const getSavedList = localStorage.getItem("myList");
   setClientList(getSavedList);
}, [])
```

So, in your useEffect you should

1. get value from local store
2. compare with value from backend
3. set new list to strage